# Handling BigIntegers in RSA implementation

Tags: java, rsa, equation, modulus

I'm trying to implement RSA encryption in Java with big integers, when obviously the modulus is being generated randomly from q,p primes, each 128 bytes -1024 bits.

My problem is that sometimes the modulus came out 257 bytes where its first byte is 0 and the second one always starts with a 1 (1******) ( star = whatever 0\1.) Other times it's a positive 256 bytes where first byte starts with 0.

When I'm sending to modPow the modulus and exponent I get:

`java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive`

even if I tried to remove the first 0 byte and remain with 256 others I get this problem.

Some code example:

```
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(1024,20,new Random());
BigInteger q = new BigInteger(1024,20,new Random());
//multiplying p & q and inserting it to modulus
ByteArray modulus = new ByteArray( p.multiply(q).toByteArray());
if (modulus.length()==257)
{
  //if the first byte is 00 then erasing it
  flag =false;
  ByteArray temp = new ByteArray(TypeUtils.subArray(modulus.getByteArray(), 1, 256));
  modulus = temp;
}

BigInteger modulusInBig = new BigInteger(TypeUtils.Byte2byte( modulus.getByteArray()) );
BigInteger answer = inTextInBig.modPow(exponentInBig, modulusInBig);
```

Comment: Don't get rid of the initial 0 byte, it belongs there. Java's byte encoding of BigInteger is compatible with a scheme called DER encoding. If the high-order byte of the positive BigInteger is >= 128 then the correct encoding is to prefix the result with a 00 byte.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) always uses one sign bit in its [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) method and its [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29) constructor. So the most significant bit of the first byte denotes the sign. If you have 256*8 bits of unsigned data, and the most significant bit in that data is 1, then you have to have an additional 0 byte to denote the fact that the number is unsigned. Removing that byte will cause it to be interpreted as a negative number, with the result you described.